# Google Cloud Platform unable to run long running process when connectivity drops

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, darkflow

I am doing custom object detection training using darkflow on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM with GPU but the long-running process dies whenever I lose connectivity or my laptop goes to sleep. I have tried running it via SSH from my Windows machine, using Google Cloud Shell, via a terminal on Jupyter Notebook on the Cloud platform and via a Jupyter Notebook on the Cloud platform directly but the process fails in all these scenarios due to a connectivity loss even though the VM is running. What is the best way to keep this long-running process going?
P.S. I did realize later that Google Cloud Shell is not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Can you execute your process from your GCE instance’s shell? If so, you can use the [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) tool. You can detach from the screen session after starting your process using Ctrl+a and then “d” and re-attach later with screen -R.

Comment: I can run the process from Cloud Shell but Google's documentation clearly states that it is not meant to run long-running processes: Cloud Shell is intended for interactive use only. Non-interactive sessions will be ended automatically after a warning. Prolonged usage or computational or network intensive processes are not supported and may result in session termination without a warning.

Comment: I found the solution here: [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Answer (score 2):

As you already write CloudShell is not suitable for that kind of job, also the work-a-rounds with screen, tmux or byobu do not help. The best practice is just to use a preemptible VM.

Some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) of the CloudShell are mentioned in the documentation:

> **Usage limits**
>
> Cloud Shell is intended for *interactive use only*. Non-interactive sessions will
>   be **ended automatically after a warning**. *Prolonged* usage or *computational* or *network intensive* processes **are not supported** and may result in session termination without a warning.
>
> Cloud Shell also **has weekly usage limits**. If you reach your usage limit, you'll need to wait until the specified time (listed under Usage Quota, found under the three dots menu icon) before you can use Cloud Shell again.